# Why not use PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(readAgain = true) in all apps?

Tags: android

Android Settings guide suggests to call `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()` with `readAgain = false`. In this case the defaults from `preferences.xml` are only loaded once when the app is launched for the 1st time (or after "clear data").

If a new preference is added, its `android:defaultValue` is not loaded, I checked.

So why nobody uses `readAgain = true`? Google results:

```
10  "PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true)"
60k "PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false)"
```

What are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is typically set to false because this one ensure that default values are only set for shared preferences that are not initialized. Keeping this to false will ensure that you do not override the setting modified by the user. This field is useful if you allow your user to re-set all app settings to the initial app settings.

Comment: I don't think, it can override a setting modified by the user. It can only load the default value.